# Dynamically retrive the java object of Object class to a given class when class name is known

Tags: java, class, object

MyInterface.java

```
publc interface MyInterface{
   void print();
}
```

Abc.java

```
public Class Abc implements MyInterface{
          public void print(){
         System.out.print("Inside Abc");
     }
}
```

Xyz.java

```
public Class Xyz implements MyInterface{
          public void print(){
         System.out.print("Inside Xyz");
     }
}
```

Main.java

```
public Class Main{

public static void main(String arg[]){

  String classPath="Abc"; // this String will get assign @ runtime.
  Class<?> s = Class.forName(classPath);
}
}
```

Here inside main method classPath is "Abc", so i'm expecting Abc Instance.
The classsPath string will be Abc or Xyz or any Class Name that implements MyInterface.So depending the classPath String i want the instance of that class. like if ClassPath is "Abc" then Abc Class instance, ClassPath is "Xyz" then Xyz Class instance.
How can i achieve this dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know what constructor to call.

Assuming all your classes have a no-argument constructor and you want that one:

```
MyInterface instance =  (MyInterface) s.newInstance();
```

If the constructor has a different signature, you need to supply that, for example with a single String parameter:

```
MyInterface instance = (MyInterface) s
              .getConstructor(String.class)
              .newInstance("foo");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object dynamically at runtime using the name of the class, input as a simple string. This is done using a part of the Java language called reflection.
Reflection allows old code to call new code, without needing to recompile.
If a class has a no-argument constructor, then creating an object from its package-qualified class name (for example, "java.lang.Integer") is usually done using these methods:

**Class.forName**
Class.newInstance
If arguments need to be passed to the constructor, then these alternatives may be used instead:

**Class.getConstructor**
**Constructor.newInstance**
The most common use of reflection is to instantiate a class whose generic type is known at design-time, but whose specific implementation class is not. See the plugin topic for an example. Other uses of reflection are rather rare, and appear mostly in special-purpose programs.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few typos in your post, so let's fix those first. `public` and `class` like

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void print();
}

public class Abc implements MyInterface {
    public void print() {
        System.out.print("Inside Abc");
    }
}
```

Then you use `Class.newInstance()` to create an `Object`, check that it's the expected type with `instanceof` and then cast like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Class<?> cls = Class.forName("Abc");
        Object o = cls.newInstance();
        if (o instanceof MyInterface) {
            MyInterface m = (MyInterface) o;
            m.print();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

newInstance Method of Class is used to create new Instance.

```
 public static void main(String arg[]){

  String classPath="Abc"; // this String will get assign @ runtime.
  Class s = Class.forName(classPath);
  Object object = s.newInstance();// to create new Instance
 }
```